# Does low sugar/fat intake cause short term memory loss?

Tags: diet

When on a strict diet (low carb or low fat), I heard that sometimes people find it hard to recollect things, even things they were thinking about a few minutes ago.

One instance, you might be going out so you know that you need to get your sunglasses, and by the time you reached reach your closet (say, in about 20-30 seconds) you forget what you were supposed to get.

Is this common?

Answer (score 3):

One of the low-fat diet risks include poor brain function, because the brain basically requires a high amount of cholesterol, which can be reduced by low levels of healthy fats in the ration. Here's some more information about [short term memory loss](https://www.smartpillwiki.com/how-to-improve-short-term-memory-definition-causes-symptoms/) and some [foods should be included in the diet](https://draxe.com/15-brain-foods-to-boost-focus-and-memory/) to prevent it.

Connection between memory loss and nutrition:

> Another cause of this problem is when you have a deficiency of certain vitamins in the body. If you don’t eat well then this can lead to deficiency of certain nutrients in the body such as vitamins that play a major role in keeping your brain in good health.

[Serum cholesterol and cognitive performance in the Framingham Heart Study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15673620)

> Lower naturally occurring TC levels are associated with poorer performance on cognitive measures, which place high demands on abstract reasoning, attention/concentration, word fluency, and executive functioning.

Comment: Note that I neither agree or disagree with what you wrote so far: This is currently quite on the short side and while I appreciate you using references, they might be improved upon in terms of quality or reliability. Inspiration for reliable sources might be found in this [meta-post](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/783/quality-of-references)